# Как разобрать XML файл и вывести на форму?

Tags: c#

http://programmersforum.ru/showthread.php?p=930317#post930317

Может вы мне сможете помочь (уже неделю мучаюсь). (

Answer (score 2):

По поводу разбора XML - можно сделать по разному: кто-то любит читать вручную, потипу примера выше, но на мой взгляд, оптимальным решением будет сериализация. Сможешь парсить свой SVG сразу в объекты с необходимыми свойствами. Сам использую для XML сериализации [YAXLib](http://yaxlib.codeplex.com/). Можно написать что-то свое: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.aspx), [MSDN2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/90c86ass.aspx). По поводу вывода - гугл говорит что вариантов рисования на форме масса, сам не пользовался, увы :(

Comment: У кого еше какие мысли?)

Answer (score 1):

Из вопроса непонятно, что и как нужно парсить и куда выводить. Обработка XML делается в .NET так

```
<users>
<user Name="a"/>
<user Name="b"/>
<user Name="c"/>
</users>
```

и

```
Xdocument document = Xdocument.load("users.xml");
var users = (from entry in document.Descendants("user")
    select new
    {
        UserName = entry.Attribute("Name").Value
    }).ToList();
```

Получили список имен пользователей - теперь выводим их на форму.

Comment: Там есть файл XML сгенирированная картинка в формате svg
ну так вот его нужно разобрать и тем самым вывести на форму